# TYPO3 news: how to link to another news within rte editor

Tags: typo3, tt-news

A question for tt_news: 
how to link within the rte-editor  - is there a possibilitiy to see a list of all news  or is there another way to link news in the text
Best reguards
Volker

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: 2 installations - typo3 7 and typo3 8

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can configure the RTE to have custom records (e.g. news) in the link wizard.

I wrote a tutorial about this for TYPO3 8LTS: https://usetypo3.com/linkhandler.html

For TYPO3 7LTS you have to use an extension like coding.ms already wrote.

Comment: @daniel i use TYPO3 8LTS: https://usetypo3.com/linkhandler.html for tx_news, but **links are only sown if i'm loged in**.
Any hint?

Comment: **Did find the solution, the page tsconfig has to be embedded in the root page than it works.**
`TCEMAIN.linkHandler.tx_news {
    handler = TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\LinkHandler\RecordLinkHandler
    label = News
    configuration {
        table = tx_news_domain_model_news
        storagePid = 20
        hidePageTree = 1
    }
    scanAfter = page
}`

Answer (score 2):

Für TYPO3 7.6.x: https://github.com/cobwebch/linkhandler
Für TYPO3 8.7.x: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79626-IntegrateRecordLinkHandler.html